# ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel breaks when decimal points supplied for integer property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the rendered view, if a user enters a value such as "1.0" or "1.2" instead of "1" then UpdateModel throws an exception if the property in question is an integer.

Is there a decent fix for this?

Comment: ofcourse it will because type not matches

Comment: I guessed as much. But I was wondering if there was an easy way to fix this.

Comment: if it is `integer` you should validate model before saving

Comment: Unfortunately UpdateModel doesn't allow you to do this.

Comment: Use `TryUpdateModel` instead.

Comment: do it on controller side @AndrewC

Comment: Why are you using UpdateModel instead of using the typical parameter model binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply block the user from entering a decimal point (or letters also in the code I provided) in the text box. I use the below code for that purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function(event) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress if it is not
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks, I think this would be the best method.